# Does the Diablo 3 contest's Price Tag Limit of 250$ include shipping?

Tags: support, diablo-3

Question is title, does the limit include shipping as in;

250$ + shipping

or

(prize price + shipping <= 250)

Comment: Presumably, since most things (everything?) are being ordered through Amazon, shipping is de facto free, no?

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Not if you're from another country.

Comment: It seems stack exchange has stepped up their cleverness in how they ship worldwide. My guess is they ship from Amazon to one of their 'distribution centers' (which is free, since their in the states) and then ship it in bulk via another shipping company. The last prize I won took extra long and wasn't shipped through a regular Amazon shipping partner. So, I'm going to guess "don't worry about shipping costs".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the total cost (prize + shipping) is under $250, don't worry about how much shipping costs.

If the total cost (prize + shipping) is over $250, please limit shipping to less than $20. There are usually ways to find the same item that will ship to you for cheaper (and quicker). For example, try to find an item that comes from the Amazon nearest your country (e.g. amazon.co.uk if you're in the UK, or amazon.de if you're in Germany).